# NullPointerException in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm having some trouble with NullPointerException showing up when I click on the positive button of my `DialogFragment`. I set a layout mainly composed of EditText and I am using their contents in my app. The problems appears when the app tries to retrieve the contents of the `EditText`

In my `MainActivity`, I set a Listener on a `Button` which calls the `DialogFragment` with the `show()` method.
Here is the code snippet describing my `DialogFragment`:

```
private class PersonalInfoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.personalinformation)
               .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.personalinformation_dialog, null))
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.edit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        EditText name_options = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_options);
                        //This line makes the app crash:
                        String text = name_options.getText().toString();
                        //doing some job...
                       }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Why does that exception happens?

Comment: Post log from logcat

Comment: Can you paste exception stacktrace and personalinformation_dialog.xml layout?

Comment: I think in this case you have to do builder.findViewById instead of just findViewById.  I'm not sure enough about that to submit as an answer though.

Comment: EditText name_options = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.name_options);

Comment: But I'm not sure You have to test it

Comment: @Konrad Krakowiak Yes it seems to work when I use getDialog()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `View` object which you are passing to `setView` for accessing `EditText` from layout of `Dialog`. do it as :

```
final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.personalinformation_dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.personalinformation)
               .setView(view)
               ....
```

Get EditText for Dialog in onClick method:

```
EditText name_options = (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.name_options);
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, even if some others like getDialog() seemed to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Bro.. when you initialize your xml controller please use this

```
yourview.findViewById(R.id.name_options);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use this:

```
EditText name_options = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.name_options);
```

Comment: It's a shame I can't accept two answers because that one does the work too.

Comment: no problem :) you can one accept and one upvote :) but choose one - which is better for you

Answer (score 0):

If line
`String text = name_options.getText().toString();`
causes NullPointerException then it is possible that `name_options` is null, so probaly there is no EditText with `name_options` id in your layout.

Comment: I did check the layout and ids before posting and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText name_options = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_options);`

this probably returns null.

Try using `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name_options)` or passing the context/view which contains the `name_options` view

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
EditText name_options = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_options);
```

to

```
EditText name_options = (EditText)getactivity().findViewById(R.id.name_options);
```